# No automatically tracked screens in Crashlytics logs. Only custom events are visible

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, crashlytics, firebase-analytics

I'm using Firebase for iOS version 9.2.0. Previously I used 8.12, but due to the problems described below, I changed to the latest version. My application has a mixed Obj-C and Swift code. It has an iOS 11 target set. I'm using Xcode 13.3.

Some time ago I realized that the Crashlytics logs had stopped saving automatically tracked screens (screen_view). It only contains custom events written manually by me.
A few months ago, the logs undoubtedly contained both.

When I check what the events look like in DebugView, everything looks fine. I can see both - custom events defined by me and the automatic ones (screen_view with parameters like class description, etc.). The situation is similar in the Events tab. I can see both.

It looks like the crashlytics logs are filtered and only the custom ones are visible, but there is no indication of it.

I must point out that I did not set FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled in the application plist file. I even tried to force YES but with no fine effect in logs.

To be sure, in AppDelegate I have set:

```
[[FIRCrashlytics crashlytics] setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled: YES];
```

The effect is still the same.

I've looked through the documentation mainly in this issue, but can't see the solution: https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews?hl=en

I also had assumptions that the iOS 14 "Do not track" feature might have it, but according to the documentation, it shouldn't affect it: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/supporting-ios-14?hl=en

Anyone have an idea how to solve this problem? I would be very grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase here,

This is correct, the Analytics default events are no longer recorded as part of the breadcrumbs in iOS. A possible workaround for this would be to file these events as Crashlytics custom logs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=ios#add-logs

Along with this, you could file a [feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/features) to include this data in the breadcrumbs.